# If $7$ does not divide $ab$, then $7$ divides neither $a$ nor $b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If 7 does not divide ab then 7 does not divide a and 7 does not divide b

So I use contrapositive for this theorem because it negates the not

So by contrapositive

If 7 divides a or 7 divides b then 7 divides ab

As I was told by my instructor i am suppose to use the following method

H1 ---> C

H2 ----> C

Then I got for H1

7 divides a

7n = a  n is an integer

H2 -->
7 divides b

7d = b     d is an integer

I dont get how to imply each of these to the conclusion!!!

Comment: $H_1 \implies C$ : If $7$ divides $a$ then $7n=a$, where $n$ is an integer. So $7nb = ab$, where $nb$ is an integer. Hence, $7$ divides $ab$. Do likewise for the other.